# Log4j: Log File correct, but Stdout only showing a subset

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, log4j

I have a problem with the configuration of my logging with log4j. All the log messages are shown as expected in the root.log file, but the stdout, however, does only show a subset of the root.log although I configured it to be the same.

**EDIT:** Precisely I am missing all messages from *a.b*.

**EDIT 2:** I am not absolutely sure, but I think that some messages from a.b. (INFO and DEBUG) get loggedd on stdout, others don't. Might that be a problem related to threads? E.g. some threads doing logging, some not?

The following is my log4j.xml, is there eventually a mistake?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
             <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] (%C:%L) %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_ALL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/root.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
             <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-4r (%F:%L) %-5p %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="a.b.master">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="a.b.master.orm.support.HibernateSessionFilter">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="a.b.master.aop.hibernate.OpenSessionInRequestInterceptor">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I am using Commons Logging as implementation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your a.b.master.aop.hibernate.OpenSessionInRequestInterceptor, you've got <level value="info" /> instead of INFO - might this be a problem? Otherwise: which messages are missing in the console output?

Comment: Okay, I'll change the info to INFO, although I don't think it makes the huge different. Thanks for the answer though. I have edited my post with some more information about the missing messages

Comment: only logger.debug messages will flow to the console. which command from logger are you using?

Comment: I am using both, log.debug and log.info. Why will only debug messages go to the console? Haven't I defined INFO which includes DEBUG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution even if not the problem directly. I added a parameter to my ConsoleAppender that everything is printed to the stderr. This now works. I guess its a problem of eclipse or log4j because if i am starting the app from the terminal (console) I can see all log messages properly.

```
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.err" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-4r (%F:%L) %-5p %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is very similar to mine where my logs are dumped into the console and to some remote host. Try this to see if it works for you:-

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        ...
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_ALL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        ...
    </appender>

    <logger name="a.b.master">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="a.b.master.orm.support.HibernateSessionFilter">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="a.b.master.aop.hibernate.OpenSessionInRequestInterceptor">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I don't think you need to define `appender-ref` in every a.b logger since it should pick up the appender from root. Also, I use `priority` instead of `logger` for root. Otherwise, your configuration looks identical to mine and I'm able to get mine working properly. If this doesn't work for you for some reason, I would suggest you to remove your custom a.b loggers from the configuration to see if you are able to get the a.b messages in your console.

Also, just FYI, I'm sure you already know this, but if your root is set to use "info", then there's really no need to set your custom a.b logger to "info" too. I usually leave my root to "warn" and have my custom loggers to override that with either "debug" or "info".